# JProfiler Profiling a new thread

Tags: java, multithreading, jsp, profiling, jprofiler

Im using Jprofiler to profile a tomcat web application.

The web application contains a file **search.jsp** .

Jprofiler hot spot shows that the search.jsp is a hot spot and from its methods, it takes long time to execute the following method:

**java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run**

This is the end of call tree, but I want to know what is happening inside this method.

Is there any way to profile methods of a new thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JProfiler always intercepts the entry point of a thread, which is the run method. Beyond that, a lot of time may be spent in framework classes that are not profiled. All that time is attributed as the inherent time of the "Thread.run" method.

To see what classes are actually called, switch to sampling and disable all filters.

Afterwards, you can enable the filters again and add appropriate inclusive filters on the "Filter settings" step.

[image]